# is there ways to enter special characters in mongodb in a collection

Tags: database, mongodb, terminal, special-characters, new-operator

i am going to add special caracter in fiels like
db.student.insert({"name":"abc","f/name":"abc"})
NOTE : Here mongodb show an error f/name is not adding so how i can add that ?

answer in more ways,

Comment: Have you checked out [$setField](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setField/)?

Answer (score 0):

While insert is deprecated (should use insertOne()), it still seems to work fine...

```
Enterprise replSet [primary] barrydb> db.student.insert({"name":"abc","f/name":"abc"}) 
DeprecationWarning: Collection.insert() is deprecated. Use insertOne, insertMany, or bulkWrite.
{
  acknowledged: true,
  insertedIds: { '0': ObjectId("63d1c044eb9ba7eec74dda8b") }
}

Enterprise replSet [primary] barrydb> db.student.find()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("63d1c044eb9ba7eec74dda8b"),
    name: 'abc',
    'f/name': 'abc'
  }
]
```